# swift passing data in textfield to mapview

Tags: swift, uitextfield, mkmapview, pass-data

I'm making an app to search the location. It contains a VC(viewcontroller) to show the searching record.
Q1. How to get the input in textfield and show the location in the mapview?
Q2. I can't unwind the viewcontroller. I've done the code and wire in the storyboard. But still do nothing.
Q3. How to pass the data in the textfield in VC A to the tableview in VC B when a button is clicked?

Or am I do it wrong?
The code:

```
@IBAction func unwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    viewController?.dismiss(animated: true)

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMap", sender: self)

}  

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Check for Location Services
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        myLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
        myLocationManager.delegate = mapViewDelegate as? CLLocationManagerDelegate
        myLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        myLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        myLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    mapViewDelegate = searchBox.text as? MKMapViewDelegate
}

@IBAction func searchButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {


    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()


    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = searchBox.text!


    /*
    //find the words
    let _ : UITextPosition = searchBox.beginningOfDocument
    let _ : UITextPosition = searchBox.endOfDocument
    let _ : UITextRange = searchBox.selectedTextRange!

    // Get cursor position
    if let selectedRange = searchBox.selectedTextRange {
        _ = searchBox.offset(from: searchBox.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
    }
    searchBox.selectedTextRange = searchBox.textRange(
        from: searchBox.beginningOfDocument,                                         to: searchBox.endOfDocument)
    */

    // myMapView.add(location as! MKOverlay)
    myMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    myMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


}
```

If your answer is useful, I'll be very appreciated.

Edit: 
(24 July 2019)Any more better answers? Although I've reproduce the problem.
It's welcomed that more answers for your reference.

Comment: The tableview in VC B is not a full version of TableViewController. Just the tableview.

Comment: The image of my app: https://imgur.com/JufHrUj

Comment: why you wanted to unwind??? you just have two VC only
use this : navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Comment: Umm...I want to do it because it enable user to back to the mapview page. It's easier to back out from the record page.

Comment: Uhh...the unwind problem I have found another way to do that... And there's another question: how to get user location in the mapview?  
`@IBAction func myLocationButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        myMapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For current location you can use the below code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    // Drop a pin at user's Current Location
    let myAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    myAnnotation.title = "Current location"
    mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
}
```

Comment: @hkuser0209 use the above code for current loaction

Comment: What is your mapViewDelegate???
change this  myLocationManager.delegate = mapViewDelegate as? CLLocationManagerDelegate  to myLocationManager.delegate = self

Comment: umm... it still need "as? CLLocationManagerDelegate"
and the first code: let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
it shows "Use of unresolved identifier "locations" " what should I do with?

Comment: @hkuser0209 are you using the same delegate method??

Comment: locationManager.delegate = self as? CLLocationManagerDelegate

Comment: @hkuser0209 refer this http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/mapview-display-users-current-location-and-drop-a-pin/

Answer (score 0):

To pass Data from one screen to another you can make use of Structs

Like:

```
struct Manager
{
    static var tfText : String = ""
}
```

To Update its content From anywhere use

```
Manager.tfText = textField.text!
```

To retrive data Same as Above

```
let variable : String = Manager.tfText
```

**you can make use of navigation controller to pop controller, if need to use unwind did you connected your source vc to unwind segue in storyboard**

Comment: If I use Popover then what to do?

Comment: that is a struct the time you just updated its value in the next second you can access its value in popover you will be using table ? Map ? Label ? anywhere you can pass value

Comment: So if I don't need to update the content, I just use the first and the third code?

Comment: That will be empty Ofcourse and nothing will be shown there